# Why is Aurra Sing so committed to helping Boba Fett seek vengeance against Mace Windu?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, boba-fett

By all accounts, Aurra Sing is a cold-blooded bounty hunter who is willing to kill or double-cross former associates once they are of no use to her or even become a threat or obstacle to her plans.

So why is she so committed to do "whatever it takes to get what Boba wants", namely vengeance upon Mace Windu? At this point in time, Boba is a helpless young boy, untrained in the art of bounty hunting, and doesn't have the heart to kill third parties as a means of furthering his objectives.

The two do not appear to be working together on a "business" relationship. Rather, Aurra seems to have taken up the role of a guardian over Boba, as the child he is. Why? Is there something she stands to gain? Did she owe a debt to Jango that she somehow feels bound to fulfil despite how ruthless she can usually be? Or is her maternal instincts or something like that inexplicably triggered?

Comment: In Legends, Boba's father Jango had been relatively good to her earlier in her life. She might also have seen some of herself in Boba, having been made an orphan essentially by the Jedi (the Jedi took her for training but it failed and then she was kidnapped from them and suffered after that), both felt the Jedi had damaged them with respect to their family and childhood, and Aurra had had a tough childhood even before that, never having a father around. She was portrayed as being a conflicted character, so beyond training a protege or seeing some profit in it, it may have been personal too.

Answer (score 1):

The *Star Wars: The Clone Wars: Character Encyclopedia* says this on Aurra Sing:

> Rumor has it that she trained as a Padawan, but left the Jedi and is now their sworn enemy. She takes a keen interest in young Boba Fett's upbringing.

From this, two possible reasons for her taking Boba under her wing emerge.

1. It's simply a matter of hating the Jedi.

In the Legends continuity, this was one of her guiding character traits.

> There is no one like me in the galaxy! I am justice! I am the bane of the Jedi! I haunt the dreams of their Padawans! I will drink your fear and spill your blood and my hate will scar the galaxy! I am Aurra Sing!

However, very little exists in the new canon to support this.

2. She felt some affection for Boba and/or Jango.

She refers to Boba as honey, and Plo Koon brings up the possibility that she wanted vengeance on Windu more for her own sake than for Boba's.

> Boba Fett: Let them go?
>
> Aurra Sing: [sighs] They're living witnesses, honey.
>
> ...
>
> Aurra Sing: I am prepared to kill you, the hostages, whatever it takes 
>   to get what Boba wants.
>
> Plo Koon: Sounds more like what you want.

Whatever the nature of her and Boba's relationship, it should be noted that it wasn't an unbreakable bond. As [StarWars.com](http://www.starwars.com/databank/aurra-sing) puts it,

> Sing taught young Boba both the skills of the hunter’s trade and the ruthlessness it required – which she demonstrated by abandoning Boba when the Jedi caught up with them on Florrum. The young Fett would learn that a hunter was loyal only to the credits.

Ultimately, we just don't know her true motivations.